# How to use the mysql I just installed?

Tags: snow-leopard, mysql

I have installed mysql in Mac OS X 10.6.6. However I don't know how to get to the mysql prompt.

```
Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:bin sarbbottam$ pwd  
/usr/local/mysql/bin
Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:bin sarbbottam$ mysql  
-bash: mysql: command not found  
Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:bin sarbbottam$
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already are in the `/usr/local/mysql/bin` directory, just launch:

```
./mysql
```

You should consider adding a symbolic link to `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` to the `/usr/bin` directory.

Comment: Not to /usr/bin that should be Apple software only as an upgrade can delete anything in there. Use /usr/local/bin which is already on the path

Comment: Or just add `/usr/local/mysql/bin` to the `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to log in to mysql, using $ ./mysql. I will add a symbolic link to /usr/local/bin. It will be great if you can assist me in creating the symbolic link or to update the $PATH variable, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all, I have created a symbolic link for /usr/local/mysql/bin to /usr/local/bin. However there was no bin directory in /usr/local. So, I have created one. $cd /usr/local; mkdir bin; ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin mysql. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Sarbbottam Bandyopadhyay: Since your comment is building the correct answer, why wouldn't you write your own one? As rightly noted by Mark, to play within `/usr/bin` is **risky** (stay polite my dear :)). Crapwares do it (for example to improve your `sudo`).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for newbies (and webdevelopers) is [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/) and phpMyAdmin (that comes bundled with MAMP). Maybe worth a thought.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to stick to Mac default provided. Apache HTTP server, PHP is configured in my MacBook Pro. The only missing link was MySql. I am able to figure it out, with expert guidance. :) More question will follow soon ...